# CSS transitions moving separate DIV

Tags: css, transition

I am trying to animate a `DIV` based on the hover state of an anchor tag, but nothing happens. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Demo at bottom.

```
.blue {
    background-color: aqua;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    -webkit-transition(margin-top 2s ease-in);
 }
a.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0px;
    -webkit-transition(margin-top 2s ease-in);
}
a.yellow:hover + .blue {
    -webkit-transition(margin-top 2s ease-in);
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

​

```
  <nav>
     <a class="yellow" href="#">YELLOW</a> 
  </nav>

  <div class="blue"></div>
```

​
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/liquidengine/btztS/

Comment: Why are the -webkit-transition properties in parentheses?

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle - I took them from compass and hadn't removed, thanks - although still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this only if you put the element that you want to move , inside the element you want to be hovered.

Like:

```
<nav>
  <a class="yellow" href="#"><div class="blue"></div>YELLOW</a>
</nav>
```

And CSS:

```
.blue {
    background-color: aqua;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    -webkit-transition:margin-top 2s ease-in;
}
a.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0px;
    -webkit-transition:margin-top 2s ease-in;
}
.yellow:hover .blue {
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

Comment: Great, that works, although I suspect there might be a bit more to it... ie using different selector options. As the original example I posted certainly didn't have nested DIVs - unless this is specific to anchor tags and the like. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a + in css selects the first sibling. I dont think it does what you are trying to do.

Here is an example using jquery to change the background color onclick in jsfiddle

Jquery snippet for changing css

```
$(".yellow").hover(function () {
    $(".blue").css("margin-top","300px");
    $(".yellow").css("margin-top","400px");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btztS/8/

Also I think you need to update your coding style somewhat. classe named blue and yellow really shouldn't exist, even in a demo. Plus in CSS you should really use hex or rgb to reference colors.

Here is the code you probably want...

http://jsfiddle.net/btztS/7/

```
.blue {
    background-color: aqua;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    -webkit-transition(margin-top 2s ease-in);
}

a.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
   display:block;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:0px;
   transition: margin-top 2s;
   -moz-transition: margin-top 2s; 
   -webkit-transition: margin-top 2s; 
   -o-transition: width 2s; 
}

a.yellow:hover {
     margin-top:400px;
}​
```

Comment: Fair play. anyway your colours confused me and I started thinking it was all abouts colours. I have updated my answer with the css that hopefully does what you need

Comment: and updated the jquery and jsfiddle for that too so that it adjusts margin

Comment: Thanks, but it;s the blue I want to move when I hover on the yellow.... I see what you mean about the colors confusing.

Comment: I beg to differ, as I have managed it using just DIVs http://jsfiddle.net/liquidengine/btztS/12/